# How to create migration of the entire DB using 1 knex script?

Tags: javascript, knex.js

In my DB I have about 50 tables. Every table has `created_at` and `updated_at`. Of course, I could create 50 migrations, but there would be similar. Is there any opportunity to create `knex` script which could be make 50 migrations to entire DB?

Here is example of code:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.alterTable("balance", table => {
    table.timestamp("created_at").defaultTo(knex.fn.now()).alter()
    table
      .timestamp("updated_at")
      .defaultTo(knex.raw("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")).alter()
  })
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.alterTable("balance", table => {
    table.dateTime("created_at").defaultTo(null).alter()
    table.dateTime("updated_at").defaultTo(null).alter()
  })
};
```

**Balance** is the name of table, so I have to create ~50 migrations changing only DB's name. Is it possible to make everything easier using just 1 knex script?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: what type of database are you using? i'm not very familiar with knex you should just be able to run a raw query for a list all tables and the iterate over that that to run your migrations for each table

Comment: I was thinking about iteration, but I don't know how to get all tables in DB using knex.js syntax

Comment: https://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#cli-list_of_databases i think you'd need to look at the relevant query to get a list of tables from that list, and then looking at knex docs, you should be able to use `knex.raw` like if you were using psql `knex.raw("SELECT tablename FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE schemaname='public'")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like that:

```
const showList = await knex.raw(
`SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'your_db';`)

for (const item of showList[0]) {
  await knex.schema.alterTable(`${item.table_name}`, table => {
    table.timestamp("created_at").defaultTo(knex.fn.now()).alter()
    table
      .timestamp("updated_at")
      .defaultTo(knex.raw("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")).alter()
  })
}
```